# CFHTTP and IIS 7 Connection Failture (NOT SSL)

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

I'm trying to do a very simple CFHTTP GET call to a local website running on IIS7, however it throws a 408 Connection Failure.

I've done all the obvious things:

1. The site is listed in the hosts file locally
2. I've added the CFHTTPPARAM tags for IIS compression issues (deflate;q=0)
3. Surfing to the URL in the browser works fine
4. Doing a CFHTTP to google.com works fine, no local sites work at all.

When searching on Google there are others that have had this, but no solutions.

Anyone successfully got through this issue?

Comment: Can you skip the hosts file and connect via the IP you put in the file?

Comment: There's lots of different sites on the same 127.0.0.1 IP

Comment: Even so, there should be one that's the default. CFHTTP should still return *something* from 127.0.0.1. That will eliminate whether it's an issue with IIS specifically, or just the particular host header you're trying to hit.

Comment: have you tried adding a valid user agent to your cfhttp tag? something like (it's an old one, I know)

useragent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"

Comment: Daniel, I tried using 127.0.0.1 just running on IIS as the default site. Still the same problem.

Comment: Travis, just tried that, same problem. The new UserAgent appears fine in the IIS logs. Still CFHTTP times out.

Comment: Dave, did you ever get this resolved? We're having a similar problem with ColdFusion 11 hitting an IIS server (with a Tomcat back end). It's also taking forever if it does get a response.

Comment: Hey matt, we did, but can't remember what it was. The VM we're using now is Win7, so might have been a Vista thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a private, or not well known certificate provider you may need to add the public key of the certificate provider to the JRUN keystore.

Here's more info on how to do that:
http://cfmasterblog.com/2008/11/09/adding-a-certificate-to-the-coldfusion-keystore/

Comment: Terry, thanks, but this is not HTTPS. 

It seems to be an IIS issue. I was previously running Apache with the same code and it worked fine. 

Why would IIS not be able to resolve CFHTTP to something locally? Perhaps ignoring the HOSTS file? Browsing works fine.

Comment: Looks like IIS receives the request ok:

#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2010-02-08 00:53:36 127.0.0.1 GET /websuite/install/suite/mssql2000.cfm - 80 - 127.0.0.1 ColdFusion 200 0 0 10541

Comment: CFHTTP returns:
Charset    [empty string]
ErrorDetail  [empty string]
Filecontent  Connection Timeout
Header  [empty string]
Mimetype  Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  
struct [empty]
Statuscode  408 Request Time-out
Text  YES

Comment: Longshot - Is it a CFM page under developer edition? TWO IP limit?

Comment: Yes it is Developer Edition. But I'm guessing it'll be the same IP requesting. The CFHTTP times out, after what ever you specify in timeout="5", it seems that IIS receives the request, but holds it and doesn't respond to CF. Almost like waiting for authentication? But don't see what that should be.

Comment: Both running on Local System account

Comment: Running the exact same code on production works fine (CF9/IIS7/Win2k3), locally it bombs (CF9/IIS7/Vista)

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to restart CF if you changed your HOSTS file after CF was started. It caching DNS entries pretty greedily.

Comment: Hey Daniel, tried all that, including complete reboot. Still nothing. I reckon it's a CF + IIS Vista permissions prob. I'm guessing CFHTTP needs permission to IIS? No idea what extra it needs. They are on the same account, and also Annoymous Authentication is enabled.

Comment: Also remember that the request appears in the IIS logs. It just never gets back to CF.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad implementation. Use cfx_http.