# CFHTTP and IIS 7 Connection Failture (NOT SSL)

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

This is the same exact problem as a previously unanswered question:

[CFHTTP and IIS 7 Connection Failture (NOT SSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218615/cfhttp-and-iis-7-connection-failture-not-ssl)

On IIS7 + CF9 on Win7, CFHTTP POST fails with a HTTP Error 408 Request Time-out most of the time when using CFHTTP on localhost on port 80 without SSL. It is successful about 5% of the time (or less), meaning intermittently it will get processed. But most of the time it just fails.

The address I call is:

http://localhost/integration/MY_KFKPortal/index.cfm?svc=KFKIncoming_MRC

which works fine from the browser. My CFHTTP code is:

```
<cfhttp url="#URL#" method="POST" result="objGet" timeout="20" throwOnError="no">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="HEADER" value="content-type:text/html;charset='UTF-8';">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#PostString#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

Anyone found the solution to this problem?

Comment: We are aware of this as a dupe, but are prepared to keep it open and merge the two questions if a solution is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

It should be two consideration for this case.

- how about removing throwonerror attribute from your cfhttp tag.
- check your firewall, router and other network for blocking cfhttp port.

Comment: - I've tried throwonerror="yes", "no" and leaving it out altogether. No difference

Comment: - This problem only occurs for Localhost. I've turned off windows firewall, no difference. Also the POST entry call appears on IIS logs. Seems like it gets lost or stuck while calling the CF ISAPI.  
  
- When I change it to call the same page on an adjacent machine (not localhost), it works fine.